# Printing all spreadsheet names only in a workbook

Tags: database, excel, 2d, excel-2007

Is it possible to print ONLY the spreadsheets names (the names at the bottom on the tabs)?
I have a workbook with quite a lot of spreasheets (over 500, er, it's a catalogue of music... CDs, what's on them, composors, conductors, movements, times etc.) and would like to do a print out of just the names of, not all and every part of the workbook.
Yes I know I should more than likely do this in Access, but I started it on a Commidore 64 years ago and have just been 'converting' it as I go along. Latest version is in Excel 2007. So esentially it's a '2D database' done using spreadsheets, rather than a '3D database' done in Access.
Many regards.

Answer (score 3):

Using VBA you can pretty easily dump the list of sheet names to a new sheet in your workbook.

```
Sub PrintSheetNames()
   i=1
   For Each sht in Sheets
      Cells(i,1).Value = sht.Name
      i=i+1
   Next
End Sub
```

Go to any blank worksheet, and then run this macro.  It will output all the worksheet names in the first column.  You can then just print the list.

Comment: To enable Intellisense on sht. add `Dim sht As Worksheet` to the top of the Sub.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you using VBA and not .NET you could write a sub routine similar to this.  The same objects and names are available in .NET.

```
Sub ShowTabNames()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim tabs As String

    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Len(tabs) > 0 Then tabs = tabs & ", "
        tabs = tabs & s.Name
    Next

    MsgBox tabs
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Perl with **[Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/)** module installed.

```
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use strict;

my $filename = shift || "Book1.xls";
my $e = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $eBook = $e->Parse($filename);
my $sheets = $eBook->{SheetCount};
my ($eSheet, $sheetName);

foreach my $sheet (0 .. $sheets - 1) {
    $eSheet = $eBook->{Worksheet}[$sheet];
    $sheetName = $eSheet->{Name};
    print "Worksheet $sheet: $sheetName\n";
}
```

Comment: ParseExcel will allow you to run through individual sheets and process deeper. Here is a reference to another question for converting XLS to CSV text files... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943153/converting-an-excel-xls-file-to-a-comma-separated-csv-file-without-the-gui

Answer (score 0):

You can make a OleDbConnection to your Excel workbook then call GetOleDbSchemaTable to get list of all tables which are nothing but list of excel sheets

ExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Python with the [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) module installed:

```
import xlrd, sys
filename = (sys.argv[1:2] or ['Book1.xls'])[0]
book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, on_demand=True)
for name in book.sheet_names():
    print name # name is in Unicode; may need encoding
```

Note: the `on_demand` arg is new in version 0.7.1; it allows saving time and memory by not parsing all the worksheets up front. If you have an earlier version, either upgrade or remove `on_demand=True` in the snippet above.