# Convert XLS to CSV on command line

Tags: windows, excel, csv

How could I convert an XLS file to a CSV file on the windows command line.

The machine has Microsoft Office 2000 installed. I'm open to installing OpenOffice if it's not possible using Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Open Notepad, create a file called XlsToCsv.vbs and paste this in:

```vb
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Then from a command line, go to the folder you saved the .vbs file in and run:

```
XlsToCsv.vbs [sourcexlsFile].xls [destinationcsvfile].csv
```

This requires Excel to be installed on the machine you are on though.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, the parameter 6 in the oBook.SaveAs function is the constant for the CSV format.

Comment: Works just fine, and not only for xls files, but also xlsx. As said by Andrew, file paths must either be absolute, or in the user "data" directory (I'm not sure what is the exact name in english). I still haven't figured out how to solve that, I'm not doing much vbscript! :)

Comment: I have posted below a slightly modified version which handles file paths better. Thanks ScottF!

Comment: I am using this (with few adaptations) to convert from XML to XLS. However, I don't want to have the compatibility warning message box from Excel during this conversion. Do you know how can I disable this warning?

Comment: The code converts only the active worksheet.  To select another worksheet, add the following line after the `oExcel.Workbooks.Open` line with the desired index of the worksheet (starts at 1):

`oBook.Worksheets(1).Activate`

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there a way to keep the intial cells formatting in the final csv file? (in my case the content of some cells of th Excel file is crossed and I'd like to have it crossed also in the csv)

Comment: Is it possible to convert all files in the folder from XLSX to XLSB?

Comment: If anyone keen to associate this vbs in a Python process, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112944/executing-a-vbs-file-with-arguments-created-by-python

Comment: It ought to be noted that this functional not just on xls or xlsx, but on any file that Excel itself can open.

Comment: a solution to convert all sheets to separate csv?

Answer (score 96):

A slightly modified version of ScottF answer, which does not require absolute file paths:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

I have renamed the script ExcelToCsv, since this script is not limited to xls at all. xlsx Works just fine, as  we could expect.

Tested with Office 2010.

Comment: I am using this (with few adaptations) to convert from XML to XLS. However, I don't want to have the compatibility warning message box from Excel during this conversion. Do you know how can I disable this warning?

Comment: Is there any way to save this file as Unicode char set?

Comment: I put this answer together with @user565869 's answer in a Gist with simple instructions. See: [Script to convert Excel File to CSV](https://gist.github.com/tonyerskine/77250575b166bec997f33a679a0dfbe4)

Comment: That's nice put together @10GritSandpaper

Comment: Is there a way to use ; as a delimiter instead of ,? I tried changing oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format, Local:=True but I get an error that a statement is expected after the :
When I added , "Local:=True" no more errors but still the , is used instead of ; as delimiter.

Maybe one of you can help me out.

Comment: i got an error: `Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks`, I'm at O365

Answer (score 34):

A small expansion on ScottF's groovy VB script: this batch file will loop through the .xlsx files in a directory and dump them into *.csv files:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.xlsx /b') DO ExcelToCSV.vbs "%%i" "%%i.csv"
```

Note: You may change extension .xlsx to .xls andname of script ExcelToCSV to XlsToCsv

Comment: @Rieaux: Regarding your comment-as-an-edit: if this gives the files a double extension, a second simple batch file can rename them.  This is drifting into a new question, though; please give it a try and, if you're unable to make it work, post a new question here on SU.

Comment: this automation saved my life. :) Thank u

Comment: I put this answer together with @plang 's answer in a Gist with simple instructions. See: [Script to convert Excel File to CSV](https://gist.github.com/tonyerskine/77250575b166bec997f33a679a0dfbe4)

Comment: @10GritSandpaper Using Excel 2007. Script in your link didn't work for me.

Comment: You can change "%%i.csv" to  "%%~ni.csv" to remove the ".xls" file extension in the csv files.

Comment: @10GritSandpaper Life-saver!  Thanks a bunch

Comment: I know this is old, but keep in mind that ```%%i``` is for batch files only, on the command line you'd use ```%i``` - I wanted to run this small loop from the CLI itself, so here's what worked for me (credits to @ShaohuaLi for the ```%~ni.csv``` idea) - ```FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('DIR *.xlsx /b') DO XLSX2CSV.vbs "%i" "%~ni.csv"```

Answer (score 22):

How about with PowerShell?

Code should be looks like this, not tested though

```
$xlCSV = 6
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application 
$Excel.visible = $False 
$Excel.displayalerts=$False 
$WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("YOUDOC.XLS") 
$Workbook.SaveAs("YOURDOC.csv",$xlCSV) 
$Excel.quit()
```

Here is a post explaining how to use it

[How Can I Use Windows PowerShell to Automate Microsoft Excel?](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx)

Comment: This looks like a good approach. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it going. I'm not familiar with PowerShell, so when I ran into an error I didn't know what to do. I couldn't find a PowerShell-specifc solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369

Comment: Here is some tips for powershell and excel, http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx

Comment: I did a test run of this and ran into problems as well. One thing I ran into was difficulty with the `$Excel.Workbooks.Open` method. It couldn't find the specified file. I worked around this by using `Get-Item` on the file and piping it to a `ForEach-Object` loop (something I'll end up doing in my final implementation anyway) for the two lines starting with `$Workbook`.

Comment: That fixed that problem, but then I couldn't find the resulting "YOURDOC.csv" - it wasn't in the same folder as "YOUDOC.XLS". I went back to old & trusty CMD and did `CD /D C:\ && DIR YOURDOC.csv /s`. Turns out the file was saved into My Documents by default. So, you need to put more into the script if you want to save the file to the same folder you're working in (if other than My Documents).

Comment: Link to Scripting Guy article at TechNet is 404.  Found the article here:   
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel/

Answer (score 9):

I had a need to extract several cvs from different worksheets, so here is a modified version of plang code that allows you to specify the worksheet name.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 3 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the sheet, the source, the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <sheetName> <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(2))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.Sheets(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)).Select
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with Alacon - command-line utility for [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) database. It works with Node.js, so you need to install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and then [Alasql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alasql) package.

To convert Excel file to CVS (ot TSV) you can enter:

```
> node alacon "SELECT * INTO CSV('mydata.csv', {headers:true}) FROM XLS('mydata.xls', {headers:true})"
```

By default Alasql converts data from "Sheet1", but you can change it with parameters:

```
{headers:false, sheetid: 'Sheet2', range: 'A1:C100'}
```

Alacon supports other type of conversions (CSV, TSV, TXT, XLSX, XLS) and SQL language constructions (see [User Manual](http://www.slideshare.net/AndreyGershun/alasql-manual-141220-1?qid=0351eced-b529-4e96-99a3-062e02ccb704&v=qf1&b=&from_search=1) for examples).

Comment: Wow! Alasql is really powerful.

Comment: If you install AlaSQL globally (npm install alasql -g) then you can use simply
> alasql "SELECT... INTO CSV(...) FROM XLS(...)"

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version that will handle multiple files drag and dropped from windows.
Based on the above works by

```
Christian Lemer
plang
ScottF
```

Open Notepad, create a file called XlsToCsv.vbs and paste this in:

```
'* Usage: Drop .xl* files on me to export each sheet as CSV

'* Global Settings and Variables
Dim gSkip
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

For Each sFilename In args
    iErr = ExportExcelFileToCSV(sFilename)
    ' 0 for normal success
    ' 404 for file not found
    ' 10 for file skipped (or user abort if script returns 10)
Next

WScript.Quit(0)

Function ExportExcelFileToCSV(sFilename)
    '* Settings
    Dim oExcel, oFSO, oExcelFile
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    iCSV_Format = 6

    '* Set Up
    sExtension = oFSO.GetExtensionName(sFilename)
    if sExtension = "" then
        ExportExcelFileToCSV = 404
        Exit Function
    end if
    sTest = Mid(sExtension,1,2) '* first 2 letters of the extension, vb's missing a Like operator
    if not (sTest =  "xl") then
        if (PromptForSkip(sFilename,oExcel)) then
            ExportExcelFileToCSV = 10
            Exit Function
        end if
    End If
    sAbsoluteSource = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(sFilename)
    sAbsoluteDestination = Replace(sAbsoluteSource,sExtension,"{sheet}.csv")

    '* Do Work
    Set oExcelFile = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sAbsoluteSource)
    For Each oSheet in oExcelFile.Sheets
        sThisDestination = Replace(sAbsoluteDestination,"{sheet}",oSheet.Name)
        oExcelFile.Sheets(oSheet.Name).Select
        oExcelFile.SaveAs sThisDestination, iCSV_Format
    Next

    '* Take Down
    oExcelFile.Close False
    oExcel.Quit

    ExportExcelFileToCSV = 0
    Exit Function
End Function

Function PromptForSkip(sFilename,oExcel)
    if not (VarType(gSkip) = vbEmpty) then
        PromptForSkip = gSkip
        Exit Function
    end if

    Dim oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    sPrompt = vbCRLF & _
        "A filename was received that doesn't appear to be an Excel Document." & vbCRLF & _
        "Do you want to skip this and all other unrecognized files?  (Will only prompt this once)" & vbCRLF & _
        "" & vbCRLF & _
        "Yes    - Will skip all further files that don't have a .xl* extension" & vbCRLF & _
        "No     - Will pass the file to excel regardless of extension" & vbCRLF & _
        "Cancel - Abort any further conversions and exit this script" & vbCRLF & _
        "" & vbCRLF & _
        "The unrecognized file was:" & vbCRLF & _
        sFilename & vbCRLF & _
        "" & vbCRLF & _
        "The path returned by the system was:" & vbCRLF & _
        oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(sFilename) & vbCRLF

    sTitle = "Unrecognized File Type Encountered"

    sResponse =  MsgBox (sPrompt,vbYesNoCancel,sTitle)
    Select Case sResponse
    Case vbYes
        gSkip = True
    Case vbNo
        gSkip = False
    Case vbCancel
        oExcel.Quit
        WScript.Quit(10)    '*  10 Is the error code I use to indicate there was a user abort (1 because wasn't successful, + 0 because the user chose to exit)
    End Select

    PromptForSkip = gSkip
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a way to do UTF-8 Encoding?

Comment: How to skip writing header in the target csv file. I absolutely dont understand the above script , but I'm using it in my automation. Thank You.

Comment: @TharunRaja  The script opens the file in excel, then does a "save as" to CSV, just like if you'd done it by hand except it hides it in the background.  Because the script itself isn't doing the conversion, and you're automating it, my suggestion would be to call a second script on the csv files this outputs, message me if you need help making one that strips out the first line of a file you pass it.

Comment: Myself I needed a more powerful version in powershell that can correctly process dates, can handle headers that aren't on the first line, and a few other things (it actually parses the individual cells rather than trusting excel).  If people express a need for it I'll post it but since this is essentially answered and we'd be changing languages I don't want to post duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Why not write your own?

I see from your profile you have at least some C#/.NET experience.  I'd create a Windows console application and use a free Excel reader to read in your Excel file(s).  I've used [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) available from CodePlex without any problem (one nice thing: this reader doesn't require Excel to be installed).  You can call your console application from the command line.

If you find yourself stuck post here and I'm sure you'll get help.

Comment: Actually, I have never written any C# ever. But I think I'll give it a crack with the Excel Data Reader.

Comment: A bit overkill don't you think. Smells of NIH.

Comment: I don't think the Excel Data Reader is NIH. First of all someone else wrote it. Secondly, it solved the problem better than full blown Excel.

Answer (score 3):

**:: For UTF-8 works for Microsoft Office 2016 and higher!**

Try this code:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 62

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))


Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an Excel OLEDB data provider built into Windows; you can use this to 'query' the Excel sheet via ADO.NET and write the results to a CSV file. There's a small amount of coding required, but you shouldn't need to install anything on the machine.

Comment: Underrated answer. Why would anyone install a third-party .DLL file when Windows has the functionality built in?

Answer (score 2):

Building on what Jon of All Trades has provided, the following (~n) removed the pesky double extension issue:
`FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.xlsx /b') DO ExcelToCSV.vbs "%%i" "%%~ni.csv"`

Answer (score 2):

Create a TXT file on your desktop named "xls2csv.vbs" and paste the code:

```
Dim vExcel
Dim vCSV
Set vExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set vCSV = vExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
vCSV.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & ".csv", 6
vCSV.Close False
vExcel.Quit
```

Drag a XLS file to it (like "test.xls"). It will create a converted CSV file named "test.xls.csv". Then, rename it to "test.csv". Done.

Answer (score 1):

I tried ScottF VB solution and got it to work. However I wanted to convert a multi-tab(workbook) excel file into a single .csv file.

This did not work, only one tab(the one that is highlighted when I open it via excel) got copied.

Is any one aware of a script that can convert a multi-tab excel file into a single .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Scott F's answer is the best I have found on the internet.  I did add on to his code to meet my needs. I added:

**On Error Resume Next** <- To account for a missing xls files in my batch processing at the top.
**oBook.Application.Columns("A:J").NumberFormat = "@"** <- Before the SaveAs line to make sure my data is saved formatted as text to keep excel from deleting leading zero's and eliminating commas in number strings in my data i.e. (1,200 to 1200). The column range should be adjusted to meet your neeeds (A:J).

I also removed the Echo "done" to make it non interactive.

I then added the script into a cmd batch file for processing automated data on an hourly basis via a task.

Comment: I think you should consider posting final version of the code with comments.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers helped me construct the following script which will automatically convert XLS* files to CSV *and vice versa*, by dropping one or more files on the script (or via command line).  Apologies for the janky formatting.

```
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line
' https://gist.github.com/tonyerskine/77250575b166bec997f33a679a0dfbe4

' https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804963/1037948
'* Global Settings and Variables
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

For Each sFilename In args
    iErr = ConvertExcelFormat(sFilename)
    ' 0 for normal success
    ' 404 for file not found
    ' 10 for file skipped (or user abort if script returns 10)
Next

WScript.Quit(0)

Function ConvertExcelFormat(srcFile)

    if IsEmpty(srcFile) OR srcFile = "" Then
        WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify at least one source path. Usage: " & WScript.ScriptName & " SourcePath.xls*|csv"
        ConvertExcelFormat = -1
        Exit Function
        'Wscript.Quit
    End If

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    srcExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(srcFile)

    ' the 6 is the constant for 'CSV' format, 51 is for 'xlsx'
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel
    ' https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm
    Dim outputFormat, srcDest

    If LCase(Mid(srcExt, 1, 2)) = "xl" Then
        outputFormat = 6
        srcDest = "csv"
    Else
        outputFormat = 51
        srcDest = "xlsx"
    End If

    'srcFile = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
    srcFile = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(srcFile)
    destFile = Replace(srcFile, srcExt, srcDest)

    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(srcFile)
    ' preserve formatting? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658845/1037948
    'oBook.Application.Columns("A:J").NumberFormat = "@"
    oBook.SaveAs destFile, outputFormat
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
    WScript.Echo "Conversion complete of '" & srcFile & "' to '" & objFSO.GetFileName(destFile) & "'"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to get your LOCAL delimiter to show up in the csv files instead of the comma/tab this is how you do it. This was soo challenging to find and I am amazed no one ran into it before 2022?

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

local = true
csv_format = 6
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, local

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

[gocsv](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv) is a great command-line app that runs on Windows and has *no dependencies* (no Microsoft Office, Libre Office or Python). It's just a single *gocsv.exe* binary.  To get it working, do the following:

1. [Download the zip file](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases) (*gocsv-windows-amd64.zip* for modern computers or *386* for older ones)
2. Unzip the file and move the *gocsv.exe* binary somewhere in your Windows PATH (*C:\WINDOWS* usually works)
3. Run the following [gocsv xlsx command](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#xlsx) like so:

```bash
gocsv xlsx file.xlsx
```