# Convert xlsx file to csv using batch

Tags: excel, csv, batch-file, xlsx

How do you convert multiple xlsx files to csv files with a batch script?

Comment: @Brian Huh? I am not the original poster, and therefor I cannot accept an answer. I just retaged the question. @Ankur has to accept the answer.

Comment: Try this one:
https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv

Comment: The answer from @Swampape works well. Would be good if the OP could mark an answer.

Comment: [in2csv](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html) is the tool

Comment: Credit to @chris-rudd Here is a version that will handle multiple files drag and dropped from windows.
Based on the above works by Christian Lemer plang ScottF [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804963](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804963) This uses VBS and needs Excel Installed

Answer (score 36):

Try [in2csv](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html)!

Usage:

```
in2csv file.xlsx > file.csv
```

Comment: This might work but not for me. I strictly partition my OS from the apps. At least one large application I wrote failed after 2 years in production and required monthly maintenance to stay current with libraries.

Answer (score 18):

Alternative way of converting to csv. Use `libreoffice`:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv *
```

Please be aware that this will only convert the first worksheet of your Excel file.

Comment: On a mac: `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to csv *`

Answer (score 17):

Get all file item and filter them by suffix and then use PowerShell Excel VBA object to save the excel files to csv files.

```
$excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false 

Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.xlsx' | ForEach-Object { 
    $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName) 
    $csvFilePath = $_.FullName -replace "\.xlsx$", ".csv" 
    $workbook.SaveAs($csvFilePath, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV) 
    $workbook.Close() 
}
```

You can find the complete sample here [How to convert Excel xlsx file to csv file in batch by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-convert-Excel-xlsx-d9521619)

Comment: Good answer but dead link now. Presumably $ExcelFiles should be something like `Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.xlsx'`

Answer (score 10):

To follow up on the answer by user183038, here is a shell script to batch rename all xlsx files to csv while preserving the file names. The xlsx2csv tool needs to be installed prior to running.

```
for i in *.xlsx;
 do
  filename=$(basename "$i" .xlsx);
  outext=".csv" 
  xlsx2csv $i $filename$outext
done
```

Answer (score 7):

You need an external tool, in example: [SoftInterface.com - Convert XLSX to CSV](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Convert-XLSX-To-CSV.htm).

After installing it, you can use following command in your batch:

`"c:\Program Files\Softinterface, Inc\Convert XLS\ConvertXLS.EXE" /S"C:\MyExcelFile.xlsx" /F51 /N"Sheet1" /T"C:\MyExcelFile.CSV" /C6 /M1 /V`

Comment: Statement "Command line is not enough powerful to convert xlsx into csv." should be removed (untrue), and "You need some external tool" should be replaced by "You can use" etc. See answer by @marbel here for instance (but there are other solutions).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-command-line?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Needs installed excel as it uses the `Excel.Application` [com object](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/03/22/how-can-i-save-a-single-excel-worksheet-to-a-csv-file/).Save this as ***`.bat`*** file:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off


    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;

var xlCSV = 6;

var objExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ARGS.Item(0));
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
objExcel.Visible = false;

var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(ARGS.Item(1))
objWorksheet.SaveAs( ARGS.Item(2), xlCSV);

objExcel.Quit();
```

It accepts three arguments - the absolute path to the xlsx file, the sheet name and the absolute path to the target csv file:

```
call toCsv.bat "%cd%\Book1.xlsx" Sheet1 "%cd%\csv.csv"
```

Comment: Worked for me with:
.\toCsv.bat "%cd%\Book1.xlsx" Sheet1 "%cd%\csv.csv"

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [@marbel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831620/712526) (which is a great suggestion!), here's the script that worked for me on Mac OS X El Captain's  Terminal, for *batch* conversion (since that's what the OP asked). I thought it would be trivial to do a `for` loop but it wasn't! (had to change the extension by string manipulation and it looks like Mac's bash is a bit different also)

```
for x in $(ls *.xlsx); do x1=${x%".xlsx"}; in2csv $x > $x1.csv; echo "$x1.csv done."; done
```

Note:

1. `${x%”.xlsx”}` is bash string manipulation which clips `.xlsx` from the end of the string.
2. [in2csv](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html) creates separate csv files (doesn’t overwrite the xlsx's).
3. The above won't work if the filenames have white spaces in them. Good to convert white spaces to underscores or something, before running the script.

Comment: Great solution! FWIW, by quoting carefully, (including `x1="${x%".xlsx"}";`) and setting [IFS to `\n`](https://superuser.com/a/409822/86708), you can handle spaces very effectively. But, there are even [more robust ways](https://superuser.com/a/409851/86708), since filenames could have newlines, too.

Comment: Great answer. The many `.xlsx` I had contained 2 blank lines at the top. Modifying the command to remove the first 2 lines (needs to be before the redirect): `for x in $(ls *.xlsx); do x1=${x%".xlsx"}; in2csv $x | sed 1,2d > $x1.csv; echo "$x1.csv done."; done` Thank you for a great option, including the bash removal of `.xlsx` avoiding the need to use bash `base` option!

Answer (score 3):

This PowerShell solution worked for me.  Other options (like csvkit) blew up due to encoding issues, but this worked:

- Run PowerShell as Administrator
- `Install-Module ImportExcel`
- Run `Import-Module ImportExcel` to see if you are able to run it.

  - If you get an error like, "running scripts is disabled on this system," you need to run something like this: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
- `cd` to the directory containing all the .xlsx files
- Run this to convert every xlsx file in the current directory into a CSV: `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.xlsx | ForEach-Object { Import-Excel $_.FullName | Export-Csv ($_.FullName -replace '\.xlsx$','.csv') -NoTypeInformation }`

When done, you may want to put your execution permissions back.  For me, that meant running `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Restricted`.

Answer (score 1):

[gocsv](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv) works on Mac, Linux and Windows and has *no dependencies* (no Microsoft Office, Libre Office or Python).  Just run the [xlsx command](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#xlsx) like so:

```bash
gocsv xlsx file.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that is simpler than most of the other answers and shows how to do multiple files at once.

To follow up on the answer by jsta (a short script using [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv)), actually it is not necessary to write a script at all. You can just put all the xlsx files in the same folder and then run xlsx2csv once.

On Windows, install Python and then type at the command-prompt:

```
pip install xlsx2csv
xlsx2csv C:\my\folder\name
```

Of course if you want a batch script then it can just consist of the second line above.

xlsx2csv has lots of [options](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) so it should work in most cases.