# Convert xlsx to csv in Linux with command line

Tags: linux, excel, csv, converters, xlsx

I'm looking for a way to convert xlsx files to csv files on Linux.

I do not want to use PHP/Perl or anything like that since I'm looking at processing several millions of lines, so I need something quick. I found a program on the Ubuntu repos called xls2csv but it will only convert xls (Office 2003) files (which I'm currently using) but I need support for the newer Excel files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thinking that anything implemented with a scripting language is going to be slow by nature seems... a little misguided, particularly since the interesting libraries in those languages tend to have backends written in C.

Comment: Excel used to be limited to 65536 rows. Now it's 1,048,576 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120596). it's going to be tough to fit "sever millions of lines" in it. just saying...

Comment: @Pavel could be over several files.

Comment: ...personally, I'd do this using the xlsv library for Python, but since scripting-based approaches are described as out of the question... *shrug*. (How is it a programming question if programmatic tools are excluded from the answer?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm currently using a PHP library to do this, and what takes xls2csv 1 second to do, takes php 10 minutes to do. Literally.

Comment: @user1390150 I believe it -- PHP is a raving pile of... well. But just because you have a really bad PHP library isn't a valid reason to write off all interpreted languages.

Comment: (err, that library name should have been xslw, not xlsv)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23726/convert-a-xlsx-ms-excel-file-to-csv-on-command-line-with-semicolon-separated

Answer (score 345):

The [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) spreadsheet application comes with a command line utility called [ssconvert](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/sect-files-ssconvert.html) that can convert between a variety of spreadsheet formats:

```
$ ssconvert Book1.xlsx newfile.csv

Using exporter Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv

$ cat newfile.csv

Foo,Bar,Baz
1,2,3
123.6,7.89,
2012/05/14,,
The,last,Line
```

To install on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install gnumeric
```

To install on Mac:

```
brew install gnumeric
```

Comment: Really the most hassle-free method of converting spreadsheets. Combined with a bash script, it will let you batch-process multiple files. `for f in *.csv; do ssconvert "$f" "${f%.csv}.xlsx"; done` The LibreOffice method could probably process other formats, but I could not make it work (it would simply open a blank file every time, even with the `--headless` argument).

Comment: @sebleblanc Not quite hassle-free. The installation is a pain given the number of dependencies (if you're doing this on a headless server). So far gcc, intltool, zlib-devel, GTK... GTK requires glib, atk, pango, cairo, cairo-object, gdk-pixbuf-2.0...

Comment: It seems that there is now way to prevent ssconvert to recompute the sheet before converting it to csv... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344918/how-to-prevent-ssconvert-to-recalculate-the-excel-file-before-conversion?noredirect=1#comment33963480_22344918

Comment: I managed to install it on a headless debian server with `apt-get install gnumeric --no-install-recommends`. The only drawback is that it fires lots of warnings **GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon** when running. A simple `ssconvert oldfile.xlsx newfile.csv > /dev/null 2>&1` will do the trick.

Comment: im not finding ssconvert for cygwin: http://screencast.com/t/4GgSOJNLa

http://screencast.com/t/seIb1GHKOI

Comment: i also tried installing gnumeric on windows and still nothing http://screencast.com/t/4QcjZVXHoh ... its a joke i guess?

Comment: @Yuck - Not sure of what your screen-shot wants to illustrate (it only shows that you don't have the binary in your cygwin PATH) but I've just tried native `gnumeric-1.12.17-20140610.exe` (no cygwin) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: To write to csv you may want the `-S` flag to write multiple sheets.  Each goes to its own file.

Comment: I've tried using this in Ubuntu 12.04 but get the following error: {ssconvert test.xlsb newfile.csv
Using exporter Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv

** (ssconvert:4973): WARNING **: Format Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx's probe changed input ref_count from 1 to 3.

** (ssconvert:4973): WARNING **: Format Gnumeric_Excel:xlsx's probe changed input ref_count from 3 to 5.
E Unsupported file format.}
Any ideas?

Comment: How can you specify the separator? `$ ssconvert -O 'separator=;' file.csv file.xlsx` or `$ ssconvert -O 'separator=; format=raw' file.csv file.xlsx` do not work.

Comment: @hhh The separator option only works with txt export type. You can use this to print to stdout: `ssconvert -O "separator=;" -T Gnumeric_stf:stf_assistant file.xlsx fd://1`.

Comment: We should probably accept this answer as the recommended solution.

Comment: Under macOS I had to use like this: `ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv Book1.xlsx newfile.csv`

Comment: The bash script of @sleblanc works fine, but does the inverse of what is asked for.

Comment: @ksyrium oopsies!

Comment: oh i just wished ssconvert was installable as a separate app! I was just trying to do this on wsl2 debian, and i cant do this, dont want all those gnome dependencies to install for my little work. A little python script will be best for this.

Answer (score 187):

If you already have a desktop environment then I'm sure [Gnumeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnumeric) or [LibreOffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) would work well, but on a headless server (e.g. any cloud-based environment), they require dozens of dependencies that you also need to install.

I found this Python alternative: *[xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv)*

```
easy_install xlsx2csv
xlsx2csv file.xlsx > newfile.csv
```

It took two seconds to install and works like a charm.

If you have multiple sheets, you can export all at once, or one at a time:

```
xlsx2csv file.xlsx --all > all.csv
xlsx2csv file.xlsx --all -p '' > all-no-delimiter.csv
xlsx2csv file.xlsx -s 1 > sheet1.csv
```

He also links to several alternatives built in Bash, Python, Ruby, and Java.

Comment: Works great, but I can get to run only as sudo (`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prettytable-0.7.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt'`). Now that I think about it, I got the same error with `csvkit`.

Comment: ....Was working great for me and allowing the extraction of each sheet to individual files using the -s option   -- where libreoffice was not able to handle the size of the sheet, xlsx2csv had no problems

Comment: Thanks! Very convenient in ubuntu.

Comment: In Debian and Ubuntu there is the `xlsx2csv` package, so you don't need to manually install it through `easy_install` but can use your package manager.

Comment: On MacOS you will need a `sudo easy_install xlsx2csv`

Comment: seems there is no `brew` formula for this, so I used `csvkit` from the next answer

Comment: xls2csv gave mixxed up a lot of column values in my case..

Comment: I have no idea how robust or feature-complete `xlsx2csv` is but it seems to be actively maintained and compared to installing Gnumeric on macOS via Homebrew which involves more than 30 dependencies and LibreOffice which is a several hundred MB download `xlsx2csv` has zero(!) dependencies, comes at just 50 KB and worked perfectly for my use case (converting the output of PaddleOCR to csv). Either install it with `pip install xlsx2csv` or download the latest [release](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv/releases) from the [Repository](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) and run `xlsx2csv.py`.

Answer (score 183):

You can do this with LibreOffice:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv $filename --outdir $outdir
```

For reasons not clear to me, you might need to run this with sudo. You can make LibreOffice work with sudo without requiring a password by adding this line to you sudoers file:

```
users ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: libreoffice
```

Comment: how would I tell libreoffice that I want the second sheet?

Comment: Allowing sudo to libreoffice for everyone without password is opening a can of worms. Please beware of the consequences, including the possibility to acquiring root permissions on a multi-user platform

Comment: this worked for me (sudo not required). My version: libreoffice-calc-3.6.7.2-4.fc18.x86_64

Comment: I just tried and first I needed sudo. Then I is because my current user had an instance of libreoffice running (playing an ods). After closing it, no sudo required.

Comment: `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to csv $filename` worked on OS X for me.

Comment: This method is good but AFAIK it will break non-ascii characters

Comment: Make sure all libreoffice instances are closed otherwise it won't work.

Comment: `libreoffice --convert-to` works well to convert between one spreadsheet format and another (I use it to read .xlsb files, by converting them to .xls first).  But for writing to CSV, it is limited to outputting the first sheet only.

Comment: To convert to utf-8, preserving non-ascii characters, use instead `--convert-to "csv:Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):44,34,76,1,1/1"`.  See [open office wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options) for details.

Comment: How do I read multiple sheets? I.e. i want to read sheet 7 only and create a .csv.

Comment: @dmeu you don't. You use another tool like `xlsx2csv` if you need that. The `xlsx2csv` tool has the `-s` or `--sheet` option which you can use to select the sheet (0 stands for "all sheets" and the default is 1). `xlsx2csv` is packaged in popular Linux distributions like Debian, Ubuntu and Arch Linux.

Comment: @dmeu: use [this script](https://github.com/colonelqubit/libreconverter). Works like a charm: `./libreconverter.py Spreadsheet.xls:"Sheet Name" output.csv`.

Comment: I had encoding problems in the csv after using this answer, the `ssconvert` answer solved the issue.

Comment: There is no reason for libreoffice to require root shell, and it could be easily debugged, where it fails with a user account.

Comment: I would be inclined to remove the "sudo" part from the answer, since it's really misleading. Probably the author installed LibreOffice using some uncommon ways, or was trying to write in an unwritable destination directory. But there is really no need to use sudo at all (yes, I've also tested that in a random GNU+Linux distribution).

Answer (score 62):

Use [csvkit](https://github.com/onyxfish/csvkit):

```
in2csv data.xlsx > data.csv
```

For details, check [their excellent documentation](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/tutorial/1_getting_started.html#in2csv-the-excel-killer).

Comment: this should be the top answer

Comment: `brew install csvkit`. And done.

Answer (score 50):

In Bash, I used this [LibreOffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice) command (executable `libreoffice`) to convert all my *.xlsx* files in the current directory:

```
for i  in *.xlsx; do  libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" ; done
```

Close all your LibreOffice open instances before executing, or it will fail silently.

The command takes care of spaces in the filename.

I tried it again some years later, and it didn't work. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101855/libreoffice-headless-refuses-to-convert-unless-root-wont-work-from-php-scrip) gives some tips, but the quickest solution was to run as root (or running a `sudo libreoffice`). It is not elegant, but quick.

Use the command *scalc.exe* in Windows.

Comment: Make sure you close all openoffice windows before attempting this, as it will silently fail otherwise.

Comment: Also, on Windows, the command is `scalc.exe` rather than `libreoffice`. Worked for me today on current stable LO version.

Comment: fwiw, this worked for me right now, on ubuntu

Comment: Caution: Export only the first page.

Answer (score 15):

Another option would be to use [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) via a small Bash wrapper for convenience:

```
xlsx2txt(){
echo '
require(xlsx)
write.table(read.xlsx2(commandArgs(TRUE)[1], 1), stdout(), quote=F, row.names=FALSE, col.names=T, sep="\t")
' | Rscript --vanilla - $1 2>/dev/null
}

xlsx2txt file.xlsx > file.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

If the `.xlsx` file has many sheets, the `-s` flag can be used to get the sheet you want. For example:

```
xlsx2csv "my_file.xlsx" -s 2 second_sheet.csv
```

`second_sheet.csv` would contain the data of the second sheet in `my_file.xlsx`.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org) spreadsheet application which comes which a commandline utility called ssconvert is indeed super simple:

```
find . -name '*.xlsx' -exec ssconvert -T Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv {} \;
```

and you're done!

Comment: Very useful and Thank you Mr.Pascal-Louis Perez

Comment: Above command 'ssconvert' only convert 65536 lines but I have more than one lacks lines, Can you able to help me?

Answer (score 6):

You can use executable `libreoffice` to convert your .xlsx files to csv:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv ABC.xlsx
```

Argument **--headless** indicates that we don't need **GUI**.

Comment: This answer was already given 8 years prior.

Answer (score 4):

If you are OK to run Java command line then you can do it with Apache POI HSSF's [Excel Extractor](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/ExcelExtractor.html). It has [a `main` method that says to be the command line extractor](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/ExcelExtractor.html#main%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). This one seems to just dump everything out. They point out to [this example that converts to CSV](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java). You would have to compile it before you can run it but it too has a `main` method so you should not have to do much coding per se to make it work.

Another option that might fly but will require some work on the other end is to make your Excel files come to you as Excel XML Data or [XML Spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx) of whatever MS calls that format these days. It will open a whole new world of opportunities for you to slice and dice it the way you want.

Comment: Do you know if this also supports .xlsx?

Answer (score 3):

As others said, executable `libreoffice` can convert Excel files (*.xls*) files to CSV. The problem for me was the sheet selection.

This [LibreOffice Python script](https://github.com/colonelqubit/libreconverter) does a fine job at converting a single sheet to CSV.

Usage is:

```
./libreconverter.py File.xls:"Sheet Name" output.csv
```

The only downside (on my end) is that `--headless` doesn't seem to work. I have a LibreOffice window that shows up for a second and then quits.

That's OK with me; it's the only tool that does the job rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use script *[getsheets.py](https://gist.github.com/scottming/99c09685360376d4cac2de7c891e8050)*. Add dependencies first:

`pip3 install pandas xlrd openpyxl`

Then call the script: `python3 getsheets.py <file.xlsx>`