# Is there any .NET Core compatible library for reading excel spreadsheet file?

Tags: c#, linux, excel, xlsx, .net-core

I need to parse xlsx file on Linux from .NET Core Console application. However, I couldn't find any library for parsing Microsoft Office files that is supported by .NET Core 5 framework.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to work with CSV files rather than Excel spreadsheets, or is that out of the question?

Comment: @Maritim I would of course rather use CSV file, but the input type is defined by our customer, so it can't be changed.

Comment: I don't suppose they can submit the data as CSV then? That's what I'd ask for at least, no point in sending an Excel file if a CSV can do the job ;)

Comment: May be try: https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core

Comment: @ŠtěpánBeneš what did you end up using?

Comment: @dyesdyes I ended up using the EPPlus library which has an unofficial version [EPPlus.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core) that runs on .NET Core. http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-xlsx-asp-net-core/

Comment: @ŠtěpánBeneš I think you can add an answer yourself. I ended up using it and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 7):

Have you taken a look at [Excel Data Reader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)?

There's also a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/2.1.2.3) if that makes it easier to install.

The API project file doesn't appear to have any COM interop requirements with Office, which is further supported by the existence of Android and Silverlight compatible projects included in the library.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to add reference to ExcelDataReader NuGet package, but it does not seem to support framework DNXCore, only full dot net framework. I have also taken look at NetOffice.Excel package, but it was the same.

Comment: You may want to try from GitHub instead.  NuGet's only as recent as the last build they published. I'm pretty sure I saw references to portable class types in GitHub.  If that doesn't work straight away, you can try to recompile from source with just DNX Core. The .Net requirement might just be at the project level. And at the worst, you'll see what .Net classes you'll need to replace to get it to work.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey, It would not be possible because the library is referencing `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll` which does not have support for .NET Core

Comment: I believe ExcelDataReader supports .NET Core now.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/) and [ssconvert](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/sect-files-ssconvert.html) to convert the incoming file temporarily to a csv.

You can write a [command line wrapper](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305994) around that to encapsulate the process.

Update: This SO post details how to use ssconvert (as well as a few other command line alternatives): [Convert xlsx to csv in linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-command-line)