# How to convert xlsx file to csv file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, export-to-csv

I need to convert xlsx into csv file using shell script. I am using RHEL 7.2 linux version. Is there any option to convert xlsx into csv file? please suggest me. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21651707/2836621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo pip install xlsx2csv

You can refer to 
https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv

Answer (score 3):

I've had good experiences with a python converter called (what a surprise!) [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv).
There shouldn't be any problem installing it on RHEL 7.2.