# Rename a filename in bash

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

Rename a filetype in bash. So when the script runs, it intakes a csv file and outputs a excel file. I want the output excel file with the same name as input file without csv extension.

I have a bash code where i need some assistance.

```
bash Log2Time.sh 20190925_psort.csv
filename="${FILE%.*}"
mv Log2Timeline_Filtered.xlsx $filename_EventIDs.xlsx
```

The input for the script is 20190925_psort.csv
I want the final output file i.e Log2Timeline_Filtered.xlsx to be renamed as 20190925_psort_EventIDs.xlsx

Comment: csv is a simple filetype and I think it's fair to say xlsx is not. The conversion of data can't simply be done by the extension. [Convert xlsx to csv in Linux with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-with-command-line) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```sh
csv_file=20190925_psort.csv
touch Log2Timeline_Filtered.xlsx
mv Log2Timeline_Filtered.xlsx "${csv_file%.csv}_EventIDs.xlsx"
```

I simulated the conversion by just creating a new file called `Log2Timeline_Filtered.xlsx`. The answer removes the `.csv` suffix using parameter expansion. Look up [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash man page to learn more about it.