# mac script that creates/renames new file based on original file: prevent from adding original file extension to filename

Tags: macos, terminal, sh

This is kind of an awkward situation to describe but I'll do my best. I have a script  that's designed to generate a certain type of file based on the preexisting files in the directory it's run on. Every time I do this, it works, but the output file, which has a different extension, still includes the original extension in the filename.
For example:

- OG: `file0001.mpg`
- NEW: `file0001.mpg.nfo`

How do I prevent terminal from printing that original extension into the new filename behind its intended extension?

Code is as follows;

```
# syntax check (must have only one parameter: input directory)

if [ -z "$1" ];
then echo "Syntax: $0 <input directory>"
    exit 1
fi

# change to the requested directory and inform the user of such

cd "$1"
echo "Preparing to loop through files in the following directory as requested: "
pwd

# create new directory called "metadata" and inform user

echo "Creating new MI-Files folder within the requested directory..."
mkdir "$1"/MI-Files

# begin creating MediaInfo text outputs from all files in directory and
# placing results in the MI-Files directory

echo "Creating MediaInfo text files..."
COUNTER=0
for i in *.*; do

#   NAME=${i%.*}
    COUNTER=$(("$COUNTER"+1));
    mediainfo "$i">./MI-Files/"$i".nfo;
done

# move metadata directory to the user's desktop

V_HOME=$HOME
mv ./metadata "$V_HOME/Desktop/MI-Files"
```

Comment: @triplee That's for batch scripts, which have very different syntax. Ture, that uses a zsh-only expansion option, but on macOS the default shell for scripts is bash.

Comment: Try `mediainfo "$i" >./MI-Files/"${i%.*}.nfo"` (see ["Rename a filename in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494560/rename-a-filename-in-bash)). Actually, the `NAME=${i%.*}` comamnd that's commented out does most of the work (it removes the original extension, but doesn't add the new one). BTW, you should probably check to make sure the original file is actually a media file (and especially not already a .nfo file), or it'll probably do something silly. And maybe check if there's already a .nfo file incase of a conflict. Finally, you don't need semicolons at the ends of lines.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I looked at a number of duplicates and ended up picking the wrong one. Needless to say, this is a very common FAQ and there are dozens of duplicates.

Comment: You are not revealing which shell you are using but some of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224766/how-do-i-rename-the-extension-for-a-bunch-of-files are portable even to POSIX `sh`

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm sure this was a duplicate, I just really wasnt sure how to find the other questions or what language to use. I tried a few searches and didn't find anything. Thanks to everyone for the input, gonna try out some of this stuff.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson you hit it on the head, actually. Thank you. Now just gotta figure out how to output the the input directory instead of a new directory within it.

Comment: That too sounds like a common duplicate, though I'm not sure exactly what you mean. `basename` can be used to trim off the directory name from the front of something, and `dirname` correspondingly returns only the directory. These can often be replaced with shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) expressions (the link is to the Bash reference manual, but POSIX `sh` supports a subset of them too).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hm, you’re right. I expected that since zsh is the default login shell nowadays, it would be used for scripts by default as well, but I suppose that would break too many things. Oh well, just throw a `#! /bin/zsh` in there. No use flagellating oneself with bash when better things are available! =)