# How to convert JSON & Excel file to Csv flat file using IICS

Tags: cloud, informatica, iics, iics-di

How to convert JSON and Excel files to CSV flat files using IICS Data Integration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way. IICS DI is NOT a data conversion utility. Yeah, I do know how it sounds.

Now, having said that: it is possible. You can define Excel as a source and Flat File as a target.

You can read JSON data and try using Hierarchy Parser with Flat File as output. This will be quite a nightmare though.

Now, I will not give a step-by-step instructions. Please give it a try and share any issues, should you come across any.

Or even better: don't give it a try and use some Excel-to-CSV conversion script like discussed [here for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line) or [here for bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557360/convert-xlsx-to-csv-in-linux-with-command-line).

Comment: I have tried Hierarchy parser for JSON and able to convert the same into CSV file as target. But I need JSON file as dynamic schema, like template will change each time, so i wanted to convert JSON file with dynamic content like header will not same for each time, How to convert this dynamic JSON files to csv automatically.?

Comment: Also, do we have any Batch script to convert JSON file to CSV file automatically, so that i can use the same script in command task and convert the same.

Comment: Source needs to refer to one schema. I don't think it is possible to have it dynamic. Informatica is not designed to be generic, rather to have tailored mappings instead. Not to mention that schemas can vary in complexity and it might not even be feasible to have one way to convert anything.