# How to convert xml file to csv file using python

Tags: python, xml, csv, file-conversion

I have a xml which i want to convert into csv but i am getting error.

In my xml file i wish to write only selected columns into csv.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

root = ET.parse('D:\\Task\\09_ActionRecorder_0.XML').getroot()

tags =[]
for elem in root:
    for child in elem:
        try:
            tag = {}
            tag["TL"] = child.attrib['TL']
            tag["CN"] = child.attrib['CN']
            tag["DT"] = child.attrib['DT']
            tag["AN"] = child.attrib['AN']
            tags.append(tag)

        except KeyError:
            tags.append(tag)
print(tags)
df_users = pd.DataFrame(tags)
#df_users.head(20)


column_name_update = df_users.rename(columns = {"TL": "Title", 
                                  "CN":"Control Name", 
                                  "DT": "Date Time",
                                  "AN": "Application Name"}) 


#new_data.head(20)

column_name_update.to_csv("D:\\Tasks\\Sample.csv",index=False, columns=["Title", 'Control Name', 'Date Time', 'Application Name'])
```

From the given xml file i wish to write only limited no of columns(as shown in code).But whenever i execute above code i am getting key error and in csv file only one column is being getting written.Kindly help if any one know how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over list of xml files and convert each of them to csv

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ATTRIBUTES = ['TL', 'CN', 'DT', 'AN']
data = []
# TODO populate the list - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir
list_of_files = []
for file_name in list_of_files:
    root = ET.parse(file_name)
    recs = root.findall('.//Rec')
    for rec in recs:
        data.append([rec.attrib.get(attr, 'N/A') for attr in ATTRIBUTES])
    with open('{}.csv'.format(file_name), 'w') as f:
        f.write('Title,Control Name,Date Time,Application Name' + '\n')
        for entry in data:
            f.write(','.join(entry) + '\n')
   data = []
```

Comment: Thanks but this code is for single xml file conversion. what I have to do if I have lets say 5 xml file which needed to be converted into individual csv file but i don't want to run code for those individually(agin and again).Is there any way where i just specify the folder which contain multiple xml file and write csv for those files individually.If you know anything about the same kindly let me know i will be highly thankful.

Comment: @Ani Do you need 1 csv per 1 xml or 1 csv for ALL xml files?

Comment: Well currently I am trying 1 csv per 1 xml but If Possible both the scenarios so that in future I might not face any problem because of the same.

Comment: @Ani I have modified the code to create 1 csv per xml file. You need to populate the `list_of_files`

Comment: And what about 1 csv for all xml if you know the same please add that also and thanks.

Comment: @Ani I will let you experiment with that.. BTW - did you test the code? Does it work for you?

Comment: I am executing the same no file is getting created or even no error also..

Comment: Did you populate `list_of_files`? If not - you need to do it

Comment: I added this line this is the folder where all log files exist 
     os.listdir("D:\\Tasks\\Task_10\\ANT_LOG\\")

Comment: Add this to the code (after you populate the list). `print(list_of_files)` . What do you get?

Comment: print(list_of_files)
[]    Blank list

Comment: @Ani This is why nothing happens.. See this code `import os
path = '.' # your folder here
list_of_files =  [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir( path )]
print(list_of_files)`

Comment: If Possible would you please tell me how to convert multiple xml file into single csv file for the above problem...

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem a few months ago, what I ended up doing was just using just using excel to save the file as a CSV, however in your case I know this might not be practical.
What I would recommend is using your python file to first convert it to CSV using bash script(would also work with power shell) 
Then iterate over your CSV file.

[This is how to create the bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256733/convert-xlsx-file-to-csv-using-batch)

[This is how you can run the script from your python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745648/running-bash-script-from-within-python)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but i dont have any knowledge regarding bash I want an python program where I can specify which columns I wanted to write from xml to csv.