# Automate Conversion of .xlsx to .csv file

Tags: unix

i would like to ask from your kind heart for any script you have on how to automate conversion of excel file to .csv, this should be done daily. Everyday there's new excel file uploaded on my FTP server with different files name, and i need it to be converted to CSV on a daily basis or if theres a new upload.

Thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256733/convert-xlsx-file-to-csv-using-batch.

Comment: Hi, thank you. But i've already see this, sad to say this is not automated and my scenario is that. Everyday theres a new uploaded excel file with different names, and i must run a script that will automate the conversion to CSV. Also, additional avoid converting excel files that was already been converted to CSV.