# Coldfusion- read large excel(xlsx) files using cfspreadsheet

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

I have a large .xlsx file (20mb) I need to read the data and create tab separated files.

I am having problems with loading this file (OutOfMemoryError) and java heap error by using cfspreadsheet

**Update**

- ColdFusion 10
- Java 7

Comment: Need some example code of what you're doing. Is this on your local machine or on a server? What version of ColdFusion? What version of Java?

Comment: So what are your memory settings? Also xlsx is a zip of xml documents. Have you tried opening the xml instead? See: https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/11/extracting-text-html-out-word-docx-files/ (Disclaimer: I did this video and it is for Word, but the concepts should still apply)

Comment: I am working coldfusion 10 with java7 and its remote machine. in administrator settings heap size was 4098mb. I am able to upload the files to server but when I read <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="upload file path" ...>  its causing the memory out error. I have no issue with 1mb files. and I tried with POIUtilities with same error.

Comment: Download the current version of CF 2021 developer edition. It also uses a newer version of Java and almost certainly a newer version of POI. See if that addresses the issue.

Comment: This might not be solvable.

Comment: @brahmam Need some more info here. How many rows do these files have? I know older versions of CF have a limit to the number of rows that can be written by `cfspreadsheet`, it might have a limit to what can be read as well. Can you try upgrading the server to use Java 8? Is your CF 10 fully patched? https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2014/10/coldfusion-10-and-11-support-with-java-8/

Comment: My advice.  Don't even bother using `cfspreadsheet`.  I've been down that road before in an older version of CF.  I can't remember if it was CF9 or CF11, but when dealing with large spreadsheets, `cfspreadsheet` is such a memory hog that there's nothing you can do to prevent the OutOfMemoryError.  The solution I found is to use a 3rd party program that accepts command line parameters and `cfexecute` it instead.  If you're using Windows, try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256733/convert-xlsx-file-to-csv-using-batch/27315498

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno there were more than 50k rows in each excel. and I must not upgrade either CF or Java.

Comment: @JamesAMohler its very old application and no plan to upgrade CF2020