# How to convert excel file to text file?

Tags: vb6

Can anyone help me how to convert txt file to xls file? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Convert XLS to CSV on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line)

I guess the above works in reverse.

If you want to work with the data itself in VB6 (I assume you do because of the tag), see this code pinched from [this thread](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=156110):

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & "C:\Documents and Settings\...\My Documents\My Database\Text;" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;"""

rs.Open "Select * from TextFile.csv", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'...
'...
'...

rs.Close
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```

CSV is a special case of TXT type where fields are comma-separated. You should be able to nominate any character including space or tab as the delimiter.

Comment: i got an error saying that user-defined type not define. What should i do? Do i need to include some refferences?

Comment: at line 1, dim cnn as new ADODB.Connection

Comment: You need [ADO](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/database-access-ado-vb6-tutorial), have you [installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168335) it? "To properly install ADO on your computer, you need to install MDAC."

Comment: what version of mdac do i need?

Comment: Just go for whatever the current official download is.

Comment: do you have a vb6 program that convert excel to pdf? Thanks!