# PHP an array of arrays to one string or one BIG ARRAY

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This code opens all excel files in a folder then it gets all emails in the file opened and puts them in an array. In the end  I need ONE BIG array from all the content from all the array of arrays. I need it to be one big array of all emails from all files.

The code below is not working. I am sure this is a simple one. Thanks

```
<?

$Folder = "sjc/";
$files = scandir($Folder);


function cleanFolder($file)
{
$string = file_get_contents("sjc/$file");
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$Emails[] = $matches[0];
return $Emails;
}



function beginClean($files)
{
    for($i=0; count($files)>$i;$i++)
        {
        $Emails = cleanFolder("$files[$i]");
        $TheEmails .= explode(",",$Emails);

        }

/// Supposed to be a big string of emails separated by comma
echo $TheEmails; // But it just echos .... ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray etc...

// WHAT I REALLY WANT IS.. one Array holding all emails, not an Array of Arrays. 
}

beginClean($files);

?>
```

UPDATE: GOT TOT WORK.. HOWEVER I am having a memory issue now as the emails total over 229911.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/public_html/StatuesPlus/CleanListFolder.php on line 33**

Here is the code that worked:

```
<?

$Folder = "sjc/";
$files = scandir($Folder);


function cleanFolder($file)
{
//echo "FILE NAME " . $file . "<br>";
$string = file_get_contents("sjc/$file");
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$TheEmails .= implode(',', $matches[0]);
return $TheEmails;

}



function beginClean($files)
{
    for($i=0; count($files)>$i;$i++)
        {
        $Emails .= cleanFolder("$files[$i]");
        }



$TheEmails = explode(",", $Emails);
//$UniqueEmails= array_unique($TheEmails);
echo count($TheEmails);
//file_put_contents("Emails.txt", $TheEmails);
}

beginClean($files);

?>
```

Comment: instead of raw excel files at least convert to csv, then getting the emails is a a snap. your regular expression will not match some valid email addresses

Comment: Thanks Dagon, I was going to do that but it has lots of excel files. I only know how to do it manually. Also this info has much more than emails. I am just taking the emails. Is there a code to convert excel to csv via php?

Comment: not via php but from the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line

Answer (score 2):

`.=` is used for concatenating strings, not arrays. But you can just keep them as strings for a while:

```
$TheEmails .= ",$Emails";
```

And then:

```
$TheEmails = explode(',', substr($TheEmails, 1));
```

Comment: Fast. Thanks. Where exactly would I put this code? In the first loop or second? Also what does the substr do and the 1?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau: The `substr` just takes off the leading comma, since the first item gets the comma too. Anyways, `$TheEmails .= ",$Emails"` replaces the other `$TheEmails .= …` line, and `$TheEmails = explode…` goes after the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is yet one issue. $Emails = cleanFolder("$files[$i]"); is turning $Emails into and arrray to its not actually the email but an array from the other loop.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Final code I used to gather multiple emails from multiple excel sheets in any give folder. **The files can be CSV, XLS, XLSX, HTML etc..** and this code will abstract the emails from multiple pages in that folder and **puts them into ONE HUGE ARRAY.** :)

```
<?
    // See below for ARRAY out put called $FinalEmails 

    // SET YOUR FOLDER HERE

    $Folder = "sjc/";
    $files = scandir($Folder);


    function cleanFolder($file)
    {

    $string = file_get_contents("$Folder/$file");
    $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

    $TheEmails .= implode(',', $matches[0]);
    $TheEmails = strtolower($TheEmails);

    return $TheEmails;

    }



    function beginClean($files)
    {
        for($i=0; count($files)>$i;$i++)
            {
            $Emails .= cleanFolder("$files[$i]");
            }



    $TheEmails = explode(",", $Emails);
    $UniqueEmails= array_unique($TheEmails);

    $Emails = implode(",", $UniqueEmails);


    function isValidEmail($email)

    {  
     return filter_var(filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);  
    }  


    for($i=0; count($UniqueEmails)>$i;$i++)
    {
        if(isValidEmail("$UniqueEmails[$i]"))
        {  
        echo $UniqueEmails[$i] . "<br>";
        $FinalEmails .= "$UniqueEmails[$i],";
        } 
    else 
        {  
        //not valid  
        }
    }


    /// An ARRAY OF Emails from multiple Excel Sheeet Cleaned
    // Cleaned of duplicates and checked if a valid email.
    $FinalEmails = explode(",", $FinalEmails);



    }

    beginClean($files);

    ?>
```

Comment: Without `substr`, though, the last element of `$FinalEmails` will be empty. Also, you don’t have to convert from an array to a string to an array. Also, is `$Emails` used?

Comment: It does work without substr. Not sure why. Yes, $Emails in this example is not used. Thanks for pointing that out. I will remove it.