# Initialisation of record 0x5B left 1 bytes remaining still to be read. Apache POI Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using the following code to convert an xls to csv and I get the error :
**Initialisation of record 0x5B left 1 bytes remaining still to be read**. I thought it might be the file, I have tried different files and it's not the case.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class Excel2Txt{

    public static void convertExcelToCSV(String fileName) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {


        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".csv"));

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);

       Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);

     Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

       // hopefully the first row is a header and has a full compliment of
        // cells, else you'll have to pass in a max (yuck)
        int maxColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        for (Row row : sheet) {

           // row.getFirstCellNum() and row.getLastCellNum() don't return the
            // first and last index when the first or last column is blank
         int minCol = 0; // row.getFirstCellNum()
           int maxCol = maxColumns; // row.getLastCellNum()

           for (int i = minCol; i < maxCol; i++) {

                Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
                String buf = "";
             if (i > 0) {
                    buf = ",";
               }

             if (cell == null) {
                    output.write(buf);
                 //System.out.print(buf);
               } else {

                  String v = null;

                  switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        v = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                     break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                       if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                          v = cell.getDateCellValue().toString();
                        } else {
                           v = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        }
                      break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                       v = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                       v = cell.getCellFormula();
                     break;
                 default:
                   }

                 if (v != null) {
                       buf = buf + toCSV(v);
                  }
                  output.write(buf);
                 //System.out.print(buf);
               }
          }

         output.write("\n");
          //System.out.println();
        }
      is.close();
        output.close();

   }


    public static String toCSV(String value) {

       String v = null;
       boolean doWrap = false;

       if (value != null) {

           v = value;

           if (v.contains("\"")) {
             v = v.replace("\"", "\"\""); // escape embedded double quotes
               doWrap = true;
         }

           if (v.contains(",") || v.contains("\n")) {
             doWrap = true;
         }

           if (doWrap) {
              v = "\"" + v + "\""; // wrap with double quotes to hide the comma
            }
      }

       return v;

   }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            convertExcelToCSV("\\C:\\Data\\test.xls");
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Is that an exception message or what?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yea its an exception, I guess because the xls format is older, because when I saved it as 97-2003 workbook it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your excel file and save it to some newer version of excel. Then test with this new file.
And use the latest release of POI.

Comment: ok that worked, but these xls files I will have are going to be the old format.. is there a way to work with those ?

Comment: Since POI can't open old formats, try to do some automatic conversion. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which may be of interest to anyone googleing this is to use libre office headless convert which will work on Linux. Pasted and modified code

```
                    String[] commandArray = new String[]{
                            "libreoffice"
                            ,"--headless"
                            ,"--convert-to"
                            ,"xlsx:Calc MS Excel 2007 XML"
                            ,"--outdir"
                            ,Paths.get(file.getPath()).getParent().toString()
                            ,file.getPath()
                    };
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Process proc = rt.exec(commandArray);
    InputStream stin = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    System.out.println("input");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
    }
    stin = proc.getErrorStream();
    isr = new InputStreamReader(stin);
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
    }
    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
                    OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(new File(file.getPath() + "x"));
                    book = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```