# How to resolve InputStream LeftoverDataException : Initialisation of record 0x85 left 18 bytes remaining still to be read

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi, xls

I am workingg on conversion of xls to csv using java and i am getting exception like this,

```
com.org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream$LeftoverDataException: Initialisation of record 0x85 left 18 bytes remaining still to be read.
    at com.org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.hasNextRecord(RecordInputStream.java:156)
    at com.org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.OldExcelExtractor.getText(OldExcelExtractor.java:169)
    at CsvConverter.main(CsvConverter.java:91)
```

Comment: Checkout this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010854/initialisation-of-record-0x5b-left-1-bytes-remaining-still-to-be-read-apache-po

Comment: Thanks for your response, I saw the Link you mentioned earlier, But it didnt help out for me. This XLS file is auto generated and i can't open and save every file manually.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer, pls also go through comments of linked answer.
Also checkout the way the below question has been posted with code. :)

[Initialisation of record 0x5B left 1 bytes remaining still to be read. Apache POI Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010854/initialisation-of-record-0x5b-left-1-bytes-remaining-still-to-be-read-apache-po)