# WScript / vbscript check if file in directory

Tags: csv, if-statement, vbscript, directory, wsh

IN THE BOTTOM CODE THAT WORKED

Working on a variation of [Convert XLS to CSV on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line) that I could use to copy xls as csv.

I just want to copy files that are not yet copied, so  need to check if file already exists in my target directory.
Was thinking something like:

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sourcefldr=fso.getFolder(sourcepath)
Set targetfldr=fso.getFolder(targetpath)
for each sfile in sourcefldr.files
    for each tfile in target
    if not file in targetfldr.files then
    'create excelfile and save as csv
```

however `file in targetfldr.files` not working

How can I avoid looping over all my target files every time?

tks in advance!

EDIT:

Incorporated @Pankaj Jaju and @Ansgar Wiechers answer and below is working!

```
csv_format = 6
sourcestring ="C:\sourcefolder"
deststring= "V:\destfolder"

Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sourcefldr=fso.getFolder(sourcestring)
Set destfldr=fso.getFolder(deststring)
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook

for each sfile in sourcefldr.files
    destname = left(sfile.name,len(sfile.name)-3) & "csv"
    fulldest = fso.buildpath(destfldr, destname)
    if not fso.FileExists(fulldest) then
        Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sfile)
        oBook.SaveAs fulldest, csv_format
        oBook.Close False
        WScript.Echo "Copied " & fulldest
    end if
next

oExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this !

```
set fso=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set sourcefldr=fso.getfolder(sourcepath).files

for each sfile in sourcefldr
    if not fso.fileexists(fso.buildpath(targetpath, sfile.name)) then
        fso.getfile(sfile).copy(fso.buildpath(targetpath, sfile.name))
    end if
next
```

Comment: This might fail, because your string concatenation implicitly assumes that `targetpath` has a trailing path separator. Which it probably hasn't. That's why you should *always* use the [`BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method for constructing paths.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers ... frankly I have forgotten about BuildPath ... but you are correct. Its a safer way to create paths.

Comment: +1, and thanks for the BuildPath hint. I keep documenting all kinds of paths with the note "must end in a backslash", and keep forgetting the backslash myself all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be add all of your target folder files into a dictionary. This way you can just use "Exists" to search for it in the dictionary.

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filesDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set targetfldr=fso.getFolder(targetpath)

'add destination files into dictionary
For Each file in targetfldr.files
  filesDic.Add file.name, file.name
Next
```

This way all you need to do is check the new filename against the dictionary

```
filesDic.Exists(file.name)
```

This will just return a true / false

Here is a bit more information about the dictionary http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13992