# Converitng an .xls file to .txt unicode file

Tags: batch-file, csv, unicode, xls, batch-rename

I have been trying to convert an `.xls` file to a `.txt` file. My file has Japanese characters so I need to convert into a unicode but have not found luck.

I have used the following code as of now :

Sample DELOIP.BAT :

```
REM INTERNAL USE ONLY 
mkdir c:\temp 
cd c:\temp 
cd "C:\Users\Public\Documents" 
REM Opening employee master
cmd /u /c type DSS_employee_master.xls>DSS_employee_master.txt
exit
cd c:\temp
```

But this does not work.

Any help in this is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to save the file in Excel as text first to be able to do this. `CMD` can't read a binary file like an .xls file. You can use some VBScript to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are scripts for doing this on superuser. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/477739/is-there-any-tool-that-let-you-batch-export-excel-tabs-to-csv?lq=1) for one example. There are others.

Another herer [Convert XLS to CSV on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line)