# How do I convert a csv file to xlsb using Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to convert a csv file to xlsb. I use the second answer from this [Convert XLS to CSV on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line), which is the code below:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

My code is the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("cscript CsvToExcel.vbs data.csv data.xlsb",
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False) # Supress any messages
```

The problem is that I can't find the right value to put as the xlsb format. I have found this [XlFileFormat Enumeration (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which has the available values, but I am not sure which one is the one I need.

**Useful Tip:** If anyone tries to convert a csv with the first item in the first line is ID, an error will occur. Change the ID to id and it will be fine, more info [SYLK: File format is not valid](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm), `xlsb` format - is `xlExcel12` with value 50 (51 In Excel for the Mac). Also, you can use [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) library for converting:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
doc = excel.Workbooks.Open('D:\\input.csv')
doc.SaveAs( 'D:\\output_bin.xlsb', 50 )
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the right value for the xlsb. Do you know if I have in a csv something like 1-0, how to not get it changed to a date when I convert the csv to xlsb ?

Comment: I get an AttributeError when trying to run this, so after reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb214129(v=office.12)) I changed the last line to `excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(outpath, 50)` and while it works if I run it line-by-line in an IDE, I still get an AttributeError if I try to run it as a script.