# Pandas to_excel write dataframe to a Microsoft Excel Binary Workbook (.xlsb)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a dataframe to a Microsoft Excel Binary Workbook (.xlsb)! I have managed to get the code working for a normal (.xlsx) file but dont know how to tweak it accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as db
import urllib
import openpyxl
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine
import numpy as np
import traceback
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter
import pyxlsb

df = pd.read_sql(sql='EXEC [prod].[spGetData]?', con=engine, params=['A'])

writer = ExcelWriter("C:/Shared/Reports/Test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel("writer", 'Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

I need it to write to the file Test.xlsb but when I change the following path to that exstension it doesnt work. I also tried to change the engine to use pyxlsb library imported but also doesnt work. Is there a workaround? Or way to write to excel to a .xlsb file (specific sheet)

> raise ValueError(f"No Excel writer '{engine_name}'")
> ValueError: No Excel writer '<module 'pyxlsb' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pyxlsb\**init**.py'>'

Comment: The error looks like you need to install the pyxlsb module. However, that is only used for reading xlsb files. I'm open to correction but as far as I know there isn't currently a Python module for writing xlsb files.

Comment: I don't think there's a pure-Python way to do this, but you could look into [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/python/export-data-to-xlsb-file.html) or [win32 bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159542/how-do-i-convert-a-csv-file-to-xlsb-using-python). Neither will be easy to integrate with Pandas, however.