# converting a large number of excel files into a single mysql table

Tags: c++, mysql, excel

I am using microsoft visual studio 10 c++ and mysql workbench.I have a large number of excel files and i want to update the content of all excel files into a single mysql table.I can create a csv file for each excel file and then import it but i want it to be done with the help of a stored procedure.I want to use c++.And this procedure has to be repeated with different excel files.

i was thinking of connecting my c++ program to both excel and mysql simultaneously(is it possible?) and reading the excel files and adding the data into the mysql table.
i have already connected my program to mysql database.
Any other approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need any C++ or stored procedure at all? MySQL can already load CSV files. All you have to do is produce them in the appropriate format.

Comment: but for that i have to manually create csv's for each excel file and then load it into mysql.

Comment: Just write a script that will do it for you :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line

Comment: This is not so easy and there many technical pitfalls in the extraction of the data from excel, especially with mixed field types.  I have written a program that also include commandline options to do this, but I am biased and believe it is the best solution.  Let me know if you are interested, otherwise consider csv which will still take a bit of extra time.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Store Procedure it will not accept bulk load or CSV import But You can use without SP. Better Try to import using C++.

Comment: i m sorry but what are u suggesting to import through c++,csv's or the excel files plz elaborate.

Comment: Import through microsoft visual studio 10 c++. Because Store Procedure won't accept Bulk Load.

Comment: u mean running mysql queries in c++.. right?but then i have to provide the csv files explicitly to the program.