# excel compare using batch file and then outputs its difference in a single file

Tags: batch-file

Is there an app that can be run in batch file that compares two excel files and then outputs its difference in a single file?

Currently I'm using GUI Tortoise to compare my excel files. But since it is more convenient to use it as a batch, I prefer having batch file.

Comment: I suppose you want to compare cell values , but not binary comparison ? But SVN tools usually provide binary comparators. How exactly you want to compare the excels?

Comment: yes sir.. cell values

Comment: What is an Excel file for you? *.xls, *.xlsx (real Excel files stored in binary format) or *.csv files (text files with raw data) opened on double click also in Excel?

Comment: I  use xls for my reports.
Ok, I've search one. It's comapared It!. It uses command line that i can use in my batch file.. the difference output of the 2 files are generated as htm. Not bad. However, do you have any suggestion? It says that it is not for free. And only have limited free trial.. but when I downloaded it, there's no indication that I still have this free trial days to use it.. So confusing... dont wanna use an app that is not free. anyway, here is the [link](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3/help/source/html/cmp_commandlineusage.htm) to what I'm talking about

Comment: See [Convert XLS to CSV on command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/). Do that with the 2 *.xls files to compare which of course should contain only data and not formulas. Then you can run a (free) text compare tool which outputs differences on lines into a text file. A simple file comparison tool is `fc.exe` installed with Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a free and nice solution as of now. [ExcelDiff](http://msws.co/en/product03.jsp) outputs differences into a htm file. the app itself can compare excel contents folder by folder. really nice because it displays clearly the differences. I'm testing it now and I encountered no problem as of now. So I guess I'll stick with this as of now.