# Batch script to change many .xlsx files to .csv

Tags: excel, loops, csv, batch-file, vbscript

I have a folder with many subfolders (1000+) and inside the subfolders are a few excel files, in .xlsx format. I want to run a batch script from the main folder, which goes into each sub folder and changes each .xlsx Excel file into a .csv Excel file.

The formatting of the file system:

```
MainFolder
---subfolder1
----->file1.xlsx
---subfolder2
----->file2.xlsx
```

etc.

From this thread: [Convert XLS to CSV on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line), I figured out that I can't just rename each .xlsx to .csv, so I made the ExceltoCSV.vbs file (the modified ScottF answer, second one down).  My understanding is that I can make a for loop in a batch file to run ExceltoCSV.vbs for each sub folder. The following line of code is something i attempted, but it didn't work. It usually says *.xlsx file is not found.

```
for /R %%F in ("C:\MainFolder") do cscript ExceltoCSV.vbs *.xlsx *.csv
```

Also tried this:

```
for /d /r "C:\MainFolder" %%F in (.) do cscript ExceltoCSV.vbs "%%F\*.xlsx" *.csv
```

Error message:

```
C:\MainFolder\ExceltoCSV.vbs(17,1) Microsoft Excel: 'C:\MainFolder\folder1\*.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
```

Comment: does the folder 'folder1*' actually exist?

Comment: hey, there was actually a formatting issue I believe. The actual error was folder1\*.xlsx, so it was already in folder1. There is a backslash in front of the asterik. I'm not sure why it's not showing.

Comment: you're escaping the asteric which is making the batch file think its part of the filename pattern.

Comment: what happens if you change the pattern to %%F\\\*.xlsx

Comment: Tried the change. Same issue is occurring. If you look at my original post, the error message is there. When I typed the error message at first, the '\' didn't show (It is showing on command prompt though)

Comment: are you sure that vbs script takes regex?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure as I'm very new to vbscript (just found a thread today and copied it into notepad). I figured that was the easiest way for now because I wouldn't have to download anything.

Answer (score 0):

The VBS script you got from SO only takes a string as an input.  What you'll need to do is create a loop with a regex pattern that builds those file names dynamically and then run the script with an input string representing each file name.  Pseudo code:

```
for loop (iterate over file names in dir){
set $file_name=$iterated_file_name_from_loop

ExceltoCSV.vbs "$file_name.xlsx" *.csv

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Once I edit the pseudocode, can I put this in notepad and save it as a .cmd file?

Comment: yea, just make sure in your for loop to use two % signs