# How to Convert XLSX file into a CSV file in the command line?

Tags: excel, csv, converters

I have a requirement to load the data from an excel file to our database. I have already built in logic to load the data from CSV file to the database. So i just want to convert our source excel sheet into CSV file so that i can use the same built in logic to load the data.

Could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert XLS to CSV on command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line).  This answer creates a short macro which can be run from the command line.