# How to read an excel file and display the output in csv format in DOS?

Tags: excel, csv, dos

I need to know if we can read an excel file through DOS command prompt and display the output in CSV format. Easiest possible way appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's stopping you from using Excel to save the file as csv?

Comment: Via the command line? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line

Comment: Use Python (Excel not needed).

Comment: @durasm Does python have an excel library?  Or are you suggesting parsing the excel formatted document and outputting CSV?  Would you handle all types of Excel documents?

Comment: @Trenin There is 'xlrd' module which reads both, xls and xlsx formats.

Comment: I actually want to read the contents of the file from a tool. the tool will run command from DOS to read it. I hope this explains

Answer (score 0):

Not completely relevant, but, in java, you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)