# Convert *.xls or *.xlsx file to pipe separated .csv file using command line

Tags: vb.net, excel, windows, csv, vbscript

I have an .xlsx file like this:

### sample.xlsx:

```
Heading     C1      C2,01,02    C3    C4
R1          1       4           7     10
R2          2       5           8     11,1
R3          3       6           9,0   12
```

I want to convert sample.xlsx file into Output.csv file [pipe separated].

Please note that I don't want any double quotes "C2,01,02".

### Output.csv:

```
Heading|C1|C2,01,02|C3|C4
R1|1|4|7|10
R2|2|5|8|11,1
R3|3|6|9,0|12
```

**I know how to produce Output.csv using manual steps like this:**

Goto control panel -> Region and Language -> Additional Settings -> update list separator field with pipe "|".

Open sample.xlsx -> save as -> from the drop down select save as type CSV(Comma delimited)(*.csv).

But I don't want to do this manually. I want to achieve the same Output using command line. For this, I have taken reference from this post:
[Convert XLS to CSV on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line)

**Code is:**

This csv works perfectly but the only problem is that it produces comma separated csv instead of pipe separated.

> ```
> if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
>     WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
>     Wscript.Quit
> End If
> csv_format = 6
> Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
> src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
> dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
> Dim oExcel
> Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
> Dim oBook
> Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
> oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format
> oBook.Close False
> oExcel.Quit
> ```

**To run the above code:**

XlsToCsv.vbs [sourcexlsFile].xls [Output].csv

I tried changing value of csv_format = 6 with many other values like 1,2,3...and so on. but it's not giving pipe separated csv.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are aware that *CSV* is the extension associated with ***C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues*? It's difficult to have a pipe-delimited comma separated values file.

Comment: Seems to be difficult to do unless you hack: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23712758/Export-semicolon-delimited-csv-file.html. A python solution to post-process the file would take 3 or 4 lines, though.

Comment: @Ken White: Okay, so can I get a corresponding Output.txt file?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: Can you please post your hack solution? I am okay with python script also. All I want is that the task of converting an xlsx to pipe separated csv should be automated.

Comment: I'm on it. Just the time to write some python code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python solution. Uses python 3.4 and standard modules except for openpyxl:

Install openpyxl:

```
cd /D C:\python34
scripts\pip install openpyxl
```

Of course xlsx file must have only 1 sheet. Formulas are not evalulated, that's the main limitation.

And the empty lines are filtered out too.

```
import openpyxl,csv,sys
if len(sys.argv)<3:
   print("Usage xlsx2csv.py file.xlsx file.csv")
   sys.exit()

i = sys.argv[1]
o = sys.argv[2]


f = open(o,"w",newline='')
cw = csv.writer(f,delimiter='|',quotechar='"')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(i)
sheet = wb.active
for r in sheet.rows:
    row = [c.value for c in r]
    if row:
        cw.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

Usage: xlsx2csv.py file.xlsx file.csv

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your script anyways, better extend it like this:

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the source and the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, 3
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(dest_file, 1)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, " ", "|")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(dest_file, 2)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Comment: the problem with this kind of solution is if there are actual comas in the cells. Otherwise it's OK.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre changed it to tab-separated... this will avoid that problem ;)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel: your script behaving differently. First, I want it pipe separated [your script is TAB seperated]. Second, I dont want any double quotes [Your script is giving double quotes].

Comment: I'll check that again... worked perfect with my test files... just a sec. (Just make sure that `Replace(strText, " ", "|")` the `" "` has a tabulator in it... not a space")

Comment: @Dirk Reichel: I am able to see PIPE after replacing space with tab in the first argument in Replace(strText, "<TAB>", "|"). Now, only 1 more problem remaining.i.e., double quotes.

Comment: @Jatin it looks like Excel will quote text depending on [CSV-rules](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)... and it seems, you can't avoid it. You could insert a `strNewText = Replace(strText, """", "")` to replace all `"` but if there are some by default, they also would be deleted (and I assume that this is not wanted) :/