# Convert XLS to CSV using VBS but keep leading zeros

Tags: excel, windows, csv, vbscript

I found an [awesome scrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line)t which works fine but I am having trouble keeping the leading zeros of cells once the conversion happens.

Using this script

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

**Before Conversion (Xlsx file)**

[image]

**After Conversion (CSV File)**

[image]

**UPDATE**

If I try adding this:

```
oBook.Application.Columns("A:ZZ").NumberFormat = "@"
```

to my script like below it has no affect for formatting number cells to text

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.Application.Columns("A:ZZ").NumberFormat = "@"
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195212.aspx

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why are the leading zeroes significant? Are they actual data, or just formatting (will e.g. the values `1234` and `01234` *both* appear in the data, and do you need to be able to distinguish between them?)?

Comment: The problem is I need the columns rendered as text instead of numerical formatting.  This is product data and that column pictured above is the SKU so it is important I have the leading zeros which seem to get lost in the conversion which is going to through off my product data if the skus (and other cells) are not accurate

Comment: Just to clarify: For example in XLSX version it is 01234 but when converted to CSV it is just 1234, I need it to keep the original formatting and not strip zeros or special characters.  Question is how can I modify the script to not format those out once the file is converted to CSV?

Comment: What is actually written to the CSV file? (Are the leading zeroes lost when you export the data, or when you open the CSV in Excel?)

Comment: Wow, I did not even consider that being a thing.  When I open the CSV file in Excel the leading zeros are lost, when I open that same file in Notepad I see the leading zeros are there.  I will go back to the kiddie pool now :)