# Import Excel with bad characters to Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xls, xlrd

I have ~300 .xls files that I need to import to Python.  I've tried xlrd and pandas read_excel and both fail the import with "Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '="XS1351'.

Roughly half the columns on each sheet have quotes and leading equalsign ="THISFORMAT"

The other half have no quotes or special characters.  Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the solution you're looking for, but you could go to CSV first, then import to Python. [Here is a way to convert quickly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line) I have also tried to import .xls files to great frustration and ended up manually opening 25 or so of them and saving as CSV.