# Is there a way to import a single specific spreadsheet from Excel using base R?

Tags: r, excel

I am stuck using an older version of R (3.4.0) and can't install  any of the helpful  packages that deal with excel.

I'm looking to import a single spreadsheet from an excel workbook with multiple spreadsheets. Is this possible in base R?

I've tried searching and so far haven't found anything helpful and frankly have no idea where to start.

Comment: Simple answer: no. You need to use a package. But the easiest solution for you will probably be to export that single spreadsheet from Excel as a CSV and import that into R.

Comment: If you are on Windows and have Excel installed then there are some command line vbs programs that use Excel to convert xls and xlsx to csv and then you can use read.csv in R.  The vbs program can be launched from R using shell or system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858195/convert-xls-to-csv-on-command-line

Comment: By "can't install," do you mean you're prohibited from doing so, or you would like to upgrade and use packages but don't know how?